# What does -- mean in git usage?

Tags: git

To delete a file one can:

```
git rm path/to/file
```

When I want to unstage a deleted file in git, I have to:

- `git reset -- path/to/file`
- `git checkout -- path/to/file`

I don't quite understand why the `--` is necessary and how the command differs from:

- `git reset path/to/file`
- `git checkout path/to/file`

other that the latter wouldn't work.

What's the rationale behind `--`?

The fatal error states:

```
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

yet I still don't quite understand the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git command some-path` and `git command -- some-path` are equivalent in all cases **except** when `some-path` could be interpreted as a commit reference. The most common case is a branch that has the same name as a file.

For example, imagine your repository has a file named `master` in its root. Then `git checkout master` would checkout the *branch* `master`. But `git checkout -- master` would check out the *file* `master` of the current HEAD and replace the local `master` file with the version of that revision.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, it would not be possible to know if `path/to/file` is a file path or a tree-ish, so it is always parsed as a tree-ish, and arguments after `--` are parsed as paths.

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what tree structure could expect here? To me, I either provide a path or a branch. How could there be trees?

Comment: It's not a branch but tree-ish, so it can be a tag, some other ref or anything else.

Comment: And how would a tag cause confusion with the syntax without `--`? Could you please add an example?

Comment: If you have a file named `bar` and a branch named `bar`, how would `git` know which to remove?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. That simple phrasing made the distionction so much clearer.